# A Cryptic Crossword in Indonesian Language (TTS Kriptik Bahasa Indonesia)

Tags: language, cryptic-crosswords

<sub>*The cryptic crosswords are actually new for me and I even struggled to solve one as English is not my first language. So I decided to look for a cryptic crossword in my language, Indonesian... And I found... nothing... not even a single cryptic clue in Indonesian language is available...* ><</sub>

<sub>*So, here goes nothing... This is my attempt to create the first-ever cryptic crossword in Indonesian language a.k.a **Teka-Teki Silang (TTS) Kriptik Bahasa Indonesia**! Of course, your feedback and opinions would be highly appreciated! ^^*</sub>

---

> [image]
>
> **Mendatar (Across)**
>   1. Bumbu Jepang, jual murah! Tanpa pakaian dalam pulau di Raja Ampat. (6)
>   5. Ujung alam baka tidak ada di dalam Bahasa Inggris. (5)
>   8. Sudah kubilang kan, disingkat di Inggris: janji tidak ada Amien Rais! (3)
>   10. Ketika donat diganti oleh nilai terendah makanan dari kedelai. (5)
>   11. Pelengket salah satu jajanan tradisional tanpa pegas. (3)
>   12. TTS ini penuh teka-teki! (7)
>   13. Demikian pula permainan kata Bahasa Inggris. (3)
>   15. Seseorang yang belum tentu sedia sebelum nilai tertinggi. (5)
>   18. Kain pembersih noda hitam di muka Tom hilang! (3)
>   19. Dengki di balik sebangsa pohon kayu. (5)
>   20. Warna nila yang memiliki kemampuan supranatural? (6)
>
> **Menurun (Down)**
>   1. Marah: tidak ada kereta api pelat logam! (3)
>   2. Setuju lingkungan kehidupan tanpa metode terbalik. (3)
>   3. Penggosok pacuan tanpa plat nomor Sumatera Barat. (3)
>   4. Terjemahkan ke Bahasa Inggris: bibir di balik tablet. (3)
>   6. Saat ketiak berantakan! (6)
>   7. Meteor diacak-acak pengendali jarak jauh? (6)
>   9. Hewan gurun tersesat di tengah kartu keluarga yang membuat menguap. (6)
>   10. Saat di dalam Taman Safari Indonesia, seperti bumbu sambal. (6)
>   14. Salah satu nama sungai kosong. (3)
>   16. Inti celah seperti pada pintu tanpa kepala. (3)
>   17. Studi S3 di luar negeri: *Pizza Hut Delivery*. (3)
>   18. Setuju, tidak setuju; tidak ada ujian! (3)

Comment: *opens up Google Translate*

Comment: So the answer is also in indonesian?

Comment: @North yes it is. This puzzle is actually intended for fellow Indonesian puzzlers (uh.. anyone besides me here? lol) as it heavily depends on Indonesian language. I'll be very amazed and may put an extra bounty if this is solved by non-Indonesian speakers due to their hardwork and effort!

Comment: Does Indonesian actually use the Latin alphabet or is it transcribed?

Comment: @North Indonesian uses regular latin A-Z (26 letters) like English

Comment: I created a chatroom: (https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/105001/teka-teki-silang-tts-kriptik-bahasa-indonesia-chatroom?tab=general) to try and solve this CC, if anyone is interested

Comment: Glad to see the universal language of the world is *Pizza Hut Delivery*!

Comment: We've done most of it, though at a couple of points we aren't too sure of the wordplay.

Comment: All done now. Maybe I should write up the wordplay explanations, but I'm going to take a break from it for now :-).

Comment: @athin Thanks for posting this puzzle! Never saw puzzle here that's entirely written on another language (I speak Indonesian too), AND get solved by someone not speaking it, using Google Translate. Cool!

Comment: Hey @justhalf, nice to meet with another Indonesian-speaker! (Which is very rare here lol.) XD Hope you enjoy the puzzle! I once in a while write "exclusive" puzzles for my Indonesian friends via Facebook tho, and rarely post them here. This one is just experimental and it's nice to see non-Indonesian speaker can solve it, even faster than Indonesian one XD

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In the [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/105001/teka-teki-silang-tts-kriptik-bahasa-indonesia-chatroom?tab=general) created by North, he and I have been attacking this, and we've finally done it.

Here's the grid:

> [image]

Wordplay explanations -- across clues:

> 1a. [bumbu Jepang -> MISO] + [jual murah -> OBRAL] minus [pakaian dalam -> BRA]; Misool is one of the Raja Anpat islands.
>  5a. [alam baka -> AKHIRAT] minus [di dalam Bahasa Inggris -> AT, because "at" is one English translation of "di"]; def is "ujung".
>  8a. [janji -> IKRAT] minus [Amien Rais -> AR]; def is "sudah kubilang kan, disingkat di Inggris" -> "I know, right?" -> IKR.
>  10a. [ketika -> TEMPO] with [donat -> O] replaced by [nilai terendah -> E, lowest grade in exams]; def is "makanan dari kedelai".
>  11a. [salah satu jajanan tradisional -> LEMPER] minus [pegas -> PER]; def is "pelengket".
>  12a. Double def, or maybe single cryptic def.
>  13a. [permaianan kata Bahasa Inggris -> PUN]; def is "demikian".
>  15a. [sedia -> SIAP] before [nilai tertinggi -> A, highest grade in exams]; def is "seseorang yang belum tentu".
>  18a. [noda hitam -> TOMPEL] minus TOM; def is "kain pembersih".
>  19a. [dengki -> SIRIK] in reverse; def is "sebanga pohon kaku".
>  20a. Double def; "warna nila" is the colour, "memiliki kemapuan supranatural" is a reference to the New Age-y concept of "indigo child".

and down clues:

> 1d. [marah -> MURKA] minus [kereta api -> KA; I think this is a standard Indonesian abbreviation]; def is "pelat logam"; OP clarifies that a mur is a nut (as in "nuts and bolts"); I'm still a little puzzled how "metal plate" clues that, but no matter :-).
>  2d. [lingkungan kehidupan -> EKOSISTEM] minus [metode -> SISTEM], reversed. Def is "setuju".
>  3d. [pacuan -> BALAP] minus [plat nomor Sumatera Barat -> BA]; def is "penggosok".
>  4d. [Terjemahkan ke Bahasa Inggris: bibir -> LIP]< = PIL. Def is "tablet".
>  6d. KETIAK*; def is "Saat".
>  7d. METEOR*; def is "pengendali jarak jauh".
>  9d. [hewan gurun -> UNTA] anagrammed to ANTU inside [karta keluagra -> KK, standard Indonesian abbreviation]; def is "menguap" or maybe "[yang] membuat menguap". This uses an indirect anagram, which is a bit naughty.
>  10d. [saat -> ERA] inside [Taman Safari Indonesia -> TSI, which I assume is an obvious thing to abbreviate by its initials]; def is "bumbu sambal".
>  14d. Double def; NIL is both nothing (kosong) and the river Nile (salah satu nama sungai).
>  16d. [celah seperti pada pintu -> KISI] without its head; def is "inti".
>  17d. First part of clue means "doctoral study abroad"; second half has initials PHD. (Apparently this is a standard abbreviation in Indonesia.)
>  18d. [tidak setuju-> PROTES] minus [ujian -> TES]; def is "setuju".

For many of these there are more verbose, but also more disorganized, explanations in the chatroom linked above. (In particular, there are lots of Bahasa Indonesia -> English translations there.)

Thanks to athin for clarifying in comments some bits of wordplay that we missed.

Solving technique, if you can call it that:

> Pick a clue. Translate it with Google Translate. Translate individual words and, where appropriate, phrases with Google Translate. Think of possible ways to parse as cryptic clues. Figure out what things we therefore need words for in Bahasa Indonesia, and get 'em with Google Translate again. Repeat until blood starts to pour from every orifice and/or you solve the clue. Repeat for other clues. (You can find some more concrete thinking-out-loud in the chatroom transcript.) In extreme cases, find Indonesian word lists like [the ones here](https://github.com/ardwort/freq-dist-id/tree/master/data) and search for words matching the patterns in the grid. We haven't done this much because it's (1) a bit cheaty and (2) a lot boring. For the last couple, I made use of a larger wordlist in the same GitHub repository. 18a: looked for words of form -E- and looked them all up in GT, looked for 6-letter words containing TOM, and saw that PEL and TOMPEL were good, with PEL even having the right sort of meaning. Google Translate didn't know TOMPEL (which is why we didn't find it earlier) but the Indonesian Wiktionary did. (Top tip: applying Google Translate to foreign-language Wiktionary pages seems to be quite effective.) With 18a out of the way, 18d was P-O and there weren't a lot of options; again Wiktionary was helpful, actually using the word "agree" to describe PRO (as opposed to KONTRA, when describing votes). Then another search of the bigger wordlist turned up PROTES and I felt very stupid for not thinking of that earlier. (Of course it means "protest", and a TES is a test or exam.)

That was a lot of fun, but also a lot of work.

Comment: No way. No flipping way! One day I will tell my grandkids "I remember the day that Gareth McCaughan solved a cryptic crossword written entirely in INDONESIAN!!" Serious kudos.

Comment: Well, I had help, and it's not completely solved yet...

Comment: Massive works and efforts are done here. Really, really, really splendid job! As I said, I'll happily give an extra bounty for this answer (and ofc the checkmark) :D -- Take your time for the wordplay explanations (only if you want to add that haha). I want to apologize first about the indirect anagram on 9d (on previous version it was a reversal indicator instead of anagram but I made a mistake for reversing rot13(hagn) to be rot13(nagh) ><). Once again, congrats and hope you're having fun solving it! :D

Comment: Explanations of wordplay are now in. (With a couple of gaps where we never figured it out.)

Comment: This has got to be one of the greatest PSE answers of all time. Just...wow.

Comment: Very well done, checkmark is given! For the sake of completeness: 5a - "at" is the English for "di"; 15a - "seseorang yang belum tentu" is actually the definition of "siapa"; 1d - "mur" is "nut" in English as in "nuts and bolts"; 16d - "inti" is the definition, "celah seperti pada pintu" clues a word "kisi", "tanpa kepala" is "headless" :) ; 17d - right, actually it's very common to abbreviate "Pizza Hut Delivery" as "PHD" in Indonesia.

Comment: I've updated the explanations in the answer accordingly. I'm not quite sure how I failed to put all the possible xISI words into Google Translate, which would surely have been enough to figure out 16d :-). Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome! Congrats on 90k @GarethMcCaughan , even before the bounty XD

Comment: Wow cool Gareth, haha